# Rounding UTC Dates to midnight in PHP

Tags: php, time

I have items in my database that need to expire after a given time period.  To keep things sensible and insure they that only expire once per day I want to round my UTC dates using php.  Does anyone see any huge problems in using this code to do so:

```
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s',strtotime(date('d M Y', time())));
```

Excused that code will give the current date but at 12:00am.  Is there a simpler/better way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a specific time then you can just enter the actual time:

```
echo date('D, d M Y 00:00:00', strototime($date));
```

Comment: I perhaps didn't explain my example completely.  I used time() for example but in my application I am pulling $created UTC values from a MYSQL database.

Comment: Still the same principle: `echo date('D, d M Y 00:00:00', strtotime($created));`